# Vector subscript out of range Issue

Tags: c++, oop, debugging, vector

I have a block of code where I declare four vectors, initialize two of them. Then I have two for loops where I am adding elements to un-initialized vectors. Then finally I am re-assigning all elements of one vector to another.

But while doing these I am getting this error - "Vector Subscript out of range". Is there any operation I am doing on vectors that I am doing wrong?

My code:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> K;
    K.insert(K.begin(),0);
    std::vector<int> tempK;
    std::vector<int> S;
    S.insert(S.begin(),0);
    std::vector<int> tempS;
    int n;
    float exptd = 0;
    float SD = 0;
    std::cout<<"How many steps: ";
    std::cin >> n;
    for (int j= 1; j<=n; j++) {
        for (int i=1; i<=K.size(); i++) { 
            if (K[i] == 0) {
                tempK.push_back(4); tempK.push_back(6);
                tempS.push_back(K[i]+4); tempS.push_back(K[i] +6);
            }
            else if (K[i] == 1) {   tempK.push_back(6); tempK.push_back(8);
                tempS.push_back( K[i]+6); tempS.push_back(K[i] +8);
            }
            else if (K[i] == 2) {
                tempK.push_back(7); tempK.push_back(9);
                tempS.push_back( K[i]+7); tempS.push_back(K[i] +9);
            }
            else if (K[i] == 3) {
                tempK.push_back(4); tempK.push_back(8);
                tempS.push_back( K[i]+4); tempS.push_back(K[i] +8);
            }
            else if (K[i] == 4) {
                tempK.push_back(3); tempK.push_back(9); tempK.push_back(0);
                tempS.push_back( K[i]+3); tempS.push_back( K[i] +9); 
                tempS.push_back(K[i] +0);
            }
            else if (K[i] == 6) {
                tempK.push_back(1); tempK.push_back(7); tempK.push_back(0);
                tempS.push_back( K[i]+1); tempS.push_back( K[i] +7); 
                tempS.push_back(K[i] +0);
            }
            else if (K[i] == 7) {
                tempK.push_back(2); tempK.push_back(6);
                tempS.push_back( K[i]+2); tempS.push_back(K[i] +6);
            }
            else if (K[i] == 8) {
                tempK.push_back(1); tempK.push_back(3);
                tempS.push_back( K[i]+1); tempS.push_back(K[i] +3);
            }
            else if (K[i] == 9) {
                tempK.push_back(2); tempK.push_back(4);
                tempS.push_back( K[i]+2); tempS.push_back(K[i] +4);
            }
        }
        S = tempS; 
        tempS.clear();
        tempS.resize(100);
        K = tempK;
        tempK.clear();
        tempK.resize(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Indexes go from `0` to `size-1`. Your `for()` loops are going from `1` to `size`. So the last iteration accesses outside the vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
for (int i=1; i<=K.size(); i++)
```

Vector indexes start at 0, and the highest index is `K.size()-1`. When `i` reaches `K.size()`, `K[i]` will access outside the vector.

It should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < K.size(); i++)
```

Comment: What changed in the past 33 minutes?